# ASP.NET Core 6 MVC scaffolded identity override - how to replace pages AFTER scaffolding?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-identity, clean-architecture

I have an inherited project that has a scaffolded identity. Everything works fine. Now, I would like to change some part of the page (example) `Email.cshtml` that is supposed to be in the `Manage` folder. However, at the time of creation, the dev did not override the file `Email.cshtml`, thus I created a new file with the exact same name.

However, the project is not recognizing the new `Email.cshtml` file at all - it's like it doesn't exist.

I'm not quite sure what I should do here, and I tried re-scaffolding the entire Identity (which didn't work), also tried copying a brand new scaffolded identity `Email.cshtml` file from another project (changed namespace etc to fit project), and nothing worked.

How do I make a new file to override Identity's scaffolded files that were deleted? Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, according to the [Official Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio);

> Generated code takes precedence over the same code in the Identity RCL (Razor Class Library)

So, you aren't supposed to "create" any class by yourself when you want to customize Identity code.

I went ahead and Scaffolded Identity in ASP.NET Core 7 MVC, and I can see the "Email.cshtml" class under "Areas/Identity/Pages/Account/Manage". Are you sure you are looking at the right location?

[image]

Comment: Yes, Im referring to that class. Maybe I was a bit unclear, sorry: The previous developer of the project did not tick the Email.cshtml to be overriden when scaffolding. So, the Email.cshtml is not there because we did not choose to override it.

Comment: sorry for misunderstanding the question. in that case, it seems to be a bug, because it should be able to generate more classes after scaffolding once. i would recommend making a backup of the project (important!), completely deleting the "Identity" area from the project, uninstalling "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design", reinstalling the package, and trying to scaffold again. if it works, you should overwrite any customized classes from the original project (again, don't forget to backup!). if it doesn't work, try one more time with reinstalling identity packages too.

Comment: the plan z could be to create a new project, scaffold properly, and migrate all of the code from the original project into the new project (which was probably obvious). you might as well upgrade to version 7 while at it! :)

Answer (score 0):

I have recreated the `Email.cshtml` and `Email.cshtml.cs` from a brand new project (and modified it to suit the current project paths/namespaces etc). I have edited the routing in other places to point it to MY `Email.cshtml` file that I've placed in another folder for now.

I must first say, after a lot of attempts to fix this, I did not once close VS and open it back again... which might've solved my problem somewhere along the way, but since it is working now with a new path, I will declare this as solved.

Comment: happy to hear you got it fixed. sounds like some dll needed to be reloaded.